# DynamoDB with Lambda to update Redis cache on Insertions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a `DynamoDB` table which I enabled the `Dynamo Stream` on.
I would like my application to be able to respond with the top100 incidents (by date) when asked.

For that, I thought of writing a `Lambda` function that will be executed whenever new data is streamed and update the `Redis` cache with the new incident (in case it is really an incident).

### Lambda code:

1. Read the current top100 incidents from cache.
2. Push to the beginning of the array the new incident.
3. Slice the first 100 incidents from the array.
4. Update cache.

One thing that worries me is race-conditions when more than 1 instance of the above `Lambda` function will be executed with different stream records.

I couldn't find more information on how `Dynamo Streams` work, so I'm not even sure the above scenario could happen, that's why I ask you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by how you define your redis operation.

Redis is single threaded and you can define your complete cache update operations in a single redis transaction.